Specify a custom storage path when registering Pandas DataFrame to Azure Blob Storage
I want to register a Pandas data frame as a tabular dataset into Azure Blob Storage. I do not want to create a unique path every time I register a new version of that dataset. Secondly, I need to specify the path which would depend on date whenever I upload a dataset. E.g. if I upload today the path should be 'data/{}'.format(current_date)
Below is the code that I used to fulfill both the requirements.
dataset = Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    target=(ws.get_default_datastore(), 'data/{}'.format(current_date)),
    name='test dataset',
    description='test dataset',
    make_target_path_unique = False
)

target parameter should make a unique folder for each day. make_target_path_unique would stop creating a random storage URI path.
The above code fails stating TypeError: register_pandas_dataframe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'make_target_path_unique'
I do not want the storage URI to change randomly whenever another version of that dataset is registered. E.g. in
https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/azureml-blobstore-xxx/managed-dataset/xxxx/ the last 4 xxxx change randomly. How can I fix this issue?

You use python sdk v2 where you need to pass the path to the data.
Here, my idea is save the pandas dataframe to csv file with current date as folder name then pass that pass for creating data asset.
Save the dataframe.
import os
os.mkdir(current_date)
df.to_csv(f"./{current_date}/data.csv")

Next create the data asset.
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes

ml_client = MLClient(
    DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
)

my_data = Data(
    path=f"./{current_date}",
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER,
    description="csvs",
    name="pandas_data",
    version="1",
)

dataref = ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data)
dataref.path

output:

Here, you will get unique path for each day and for every data changes.
Note: Instead of saving the dataframe locally save it in storage account associated with ml workspace. Refer this stack solution for more information.

@Lopez Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
